# What is the default weight allocation in solving multi-objective on CPLEX?

Tags: multi-objective-optimization, docplex

I am currently working on a multi-objective problem where I am trying to minimize cost and time. I am using Docplex to solve it, but I did not specify any weight using the following code:

```
mdl.set_multi_objective(ObjectiveSense.Minimize, [totalcost,cumultime], priorities=[1, 2])
```

Understandably, I did set a lexicographic order, but I would like to know what is the default weight allocation. Should I assume that by solving it, Docplex also determines the optimal weight allocation ? If you can provide the relevant documentation, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You don't need weights to find a lexicographically optimal solution (or to solve multi objective problems in general actually). You solve two problems, or handle it implicitly in the branch and bound process

Comment: I now get it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weights are defined by you to tell CPLEX how objectives with the same priorities are blended together. If you don't define weights, by default they are all assumed to be equal to 1.

Let's assume in your example that you have 3 objectives: `[obj1, obj2, obj3]` with the following priorities and weights:

`mdl.set_multi_objective(ObjectiveSense.Minimize, [obj1, obj2, obj3], priorities=[1, 2, 2], weights=[1, 80, 20])`

Here, `obj2` and `obj3` have the same priority. So, they are blended together and the weights you define are used for that blending (making that objective a weighted sum).
Basically, the CPLEX first solves for `obj1` and find `sol1` for it. Then it adds the constraint that $obj1 \le sol1$ (since you're minimizing) and solves for `80obj2 + 20obj3`. If you don't provide any weights, you're solving for `obj2 + obj3` (remember, we assigned the same priorities to these two objectives)

Comment: Thank you, so in my case, I have $Z\ = \ totalcost \ +\ cumultime$ with the additional constraint you mentioned once the prioritized objective has been solved. I also went on https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/lexicographic-method and got that it is a method to solving multi-objective problems as it is a unique approach to specifying preferences, does not require that the objective functions be normalized, and always provides a Pareto optimal solution.

Comment: So, in your case, the model first solves for `min z = cumultime` since it has a higher priority. Then it adds the obtain value (let's call it z1) and add a constraint of the form `cumultime <=z1` and solve for min z = totalcost.

Comment: In my case, it would be solving for $min \ Z_{1} \ = \ totalcost$ as the cost is my first objective with priority 1. Once $Z_{1}$ is obtained, then we add the constraint $totalcost \ \leq \ Z_{1}$ and solve for $min \ Z_{2} \ = \ cumultime$. That's how it shows in my solution log.

Comment: In CPLEX, sub-problems are solved one after the other in the order of decreasing priorities. Check [this notebook](https://notebook.community/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/examples/mp/jupyter/nurses_pandas-multi_objective) from CPLEX for an example

Comment: Thank you. It was specified in my own link. I stand corrected :).